# cannot find Microsoft Excel XX.Y Object Library under Project->Add Reference->COM in visual studio

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I had the problem Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application' is not defined. But I cannot find Microsoft Excel XX.Y Object Library under Project->Add Reference->COM in visual studio.

[image]

**Is it because I refreshed my pc and excel uninstalled?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is because you refreshed your PC. Excel must be installed in order to use the COM APIs.